# How to export environment variables from files in bazel

Tags: environment-variables, bazel

`bazel --action_env` can specify variables one by one

If there is `.env` file, how can I export it?

Comment: Generally using `--action_env` or globally setting environmental variables is problematic as it's a bit coarse. I.e. if trying to pass information to specific tool, it's prudent to leave all the other tools (actions) out of it. But besides that, what does your `.env` file look like? Whichever way it looks, and if you are absolutely sure that is the way to proceed, you can always read it on the command line and use command expensation in shell to get `--action_env var=val` pairs; or set the variables read es environment to exec bazel in.

Comment: @OndrejK. Thanks for replying. Each line in an `env` file is in `VAR=VAL` format. I think Bazel should has an option to load the whole file to export the env. Just like this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it on a U*X like system, for the format of your file one `var=val` pair per each line, you can run something like this (note this is a bit naive and will break if there are whitespace characters in any variable value):

```
bazel build $(while read l; do echo "--action_env $l"; done < .env) //target
```

It literally adds `--action_env line_of_input_from_your_file` for each line of input onto the command line.

Or (this is a little more robust and should not care about spaces, but it also needs `xargs` to work):

```
while read l; do echo -ne "--action_env\0$l\0"; done < .env \
    | xargs -x0 bazel build //target
```

This reads each line of input and prints `--action_env` and the line itself both terminated by a null character. `xargs` will then run `bazel build //target` followed by each null separated item (`-0`) from the previous step as an additional argument. The `-x` is there to make sure we fail instead of splitting the inputs into multiple `bazel` invocations if the resulting line was too long (exceeding permissible limits).

But no, bazel does not have a dedicated command line option to read a file of the format you have described (or any for that matter) and use it to define environment for its actions. Generally speaking, such manipulation would appear to have very broad impact and is not entirely likely to be well justifiable. I.e. if you really need to do that and you are sure that is the way to proceed, you need to use another tool, such as shell, to prepare the command line to run `bazel` or populate the environment in which `bazel` command is to run.